# Fragmentation DB ::table() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop

this code work successfully

```
$table_data = DB::table('users')->select('*')->get();
```

but in this code i have error

```
$result = new DB;
$result->table('users');
$result->select('*');
$table_data =$result->get();
```

//after it work i will add (if and else if) which i can't use it in the first way

the error is:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table()

How can I solve this?

Comment: "after it work i will add (if and else if" what do you mean ?

Comment: Add your `if`s to the query directly with `where()` for example.

Comment: why you are using `->select('*')` you don't need that

Comment: if($foreignkey)
            $result->leftJoin('country', "$table.country", '=', 'country.id');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solve  is

```
$result = DB::table('users');
$result->select('*');
$table_data =$result->get();
```

thanks for you

Comment: I know this is not the answer to your question but if you have look at what you have answered is that the ::table is a static function. That is why you don't need to create a new DB class. More information and understanding won't hurt.